# Excel VBA Matrix error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, office365

```
Const A As String = "Ark1"
Const B As String = "Hans"

Sub test2()
    Dim y As Long
    Dim formulaP1 As String
    Dim formulaP2 As String
    Dim formulaP3 As String
    Dim formulaP4 As String
    Dim formulaP5 As String
    Dim formulaP6 As String
    Dim formulaP7 As String

    y = Sheets(B).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    formulaP1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX('" & A & "'!$E$2:$E$" & y & ",X_X_X()"
    formulaP2 = "MATCH(RIGHT(CELL(""filename"",$A$1),Y_Y_Y()"
    formulaP3 = "LEN(CELL(""filename"",$A$1))-Z_Z_Z()"
    formulaP4 = "FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",$A$1)))&W_W_W()"
    formulaP5 = B & "!D2&" & B & "!C2,'" & A & "'!$C$2:$C$" & y & "V_V_V()"
    formulaP6 = "&IF(SEARCH(D2,'" & A & "'!$D$2:$D$" & y & ",1)>0," & B & "!D2,)&IF(SEARCH(C2,'" & A & "'!$G$2:$G$" & y & ",1)U_U_U()"
    formulaP7 = ">0," & B & "!C2,))),"""")"

    Sheets(B).Range("A1").Select
    With Sheets(B).Range("J2:J" & y)
            .FormulaArray = formulaP1
            .Replace What:="X_X_X()", Replacement:=formulaP2, lookat:=xlPart
            .Replace What:="Y_Y_Y()", Replacement:=formulaP3, lookat:=xlPart
            .Replace What:="Z_Z_Z()", Replacement:=formulaP4, lookat:=xlPart
            .Replace What:="W_W_W()", Replacement:=formulaP5, lookat:=xlPart
            .Replace What:="V_V_V()", Replacement:=formulaP6, lookat:=xlPart
            .Replace What:="U_U_U()", Replacement:=formulaP7, lookat:=xlPart
        '.FormulaArray = _
        '    "=IFERROR(INDEX('" & A & "'!$E$2:$E$" & y & ",MATCH(RIGHT(CELL(""filename"",$A$1),LEN(CELL(""filename"",$A$1))-FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",$A$1)))&" & B & "!D2&" & B & "!C2,'" & A & "'!$C$2:$C$" & y & "&IF(SEARCH(D2,'" & A & "'!$D$2:$D$" & y & ",1)>0," & B & "!D2,)&IF(SEARCH(C2,'" & A & "'!$G$2:$G$" & y & ",1)>0," & B & "!C2,))),"""")"
        .FillDown
    End With
End Sub
```

I just get an Error: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

The real Matrix code is:

```
"=IFERROR(INDEX('" & A & "'!$E$2:$E$" & y & ",MATCH(RIGHT(CELL(""filename"",$A$1),LEN(CELL(""filename"",$A$1))-FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",$A$1)))&" & B & "!D2&" & B & "!C2,'" & A & "'!$C$2:$C$" & y & "&IF(SEARCH(D2,'" & A & "'!$D$2:$D$" & y & ",1)>0," & B & "!D2,)&IF(SEARCH(C2,'" & A & "'!$G$2:$G$" & y & ",1)>0," & B & "!C2,))),"""")"
```

But that also give the same error code, so I really need your help.

What have I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I believe that you’re supposed to use double quotes “””” when you include strings in formulas like this and not quotes surrounded by apostrophes ‘“”’

Comment: `CELL(""filename"",$A$1)))&" & B & "!D2&" & B & "!C2` looks henky. Change the first `=` to `'=` and examine the formula as text to see what's wrong.

Comment: Better yet, what does the actual formula look like and what are you trying to do? Newer functions can often replace the reliance on array formulas for complex formulas.

Comment: '=IFERROR(INDEX('Ark1'!$E$2:$E$32,MATCH(RIGHT(CELL("filename",$A$1),LEN(CELL("filename",$A$1))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1)))&Hans!D2&Hans!C2,'Ark1'!$C$2:$C$32&IF(SEARCH(D2,'Ark1'!$D$2:$D$32,1)>0,Hans!D2,)&IF(SEARCH(C2,'Ark1'!$G$2:$G$32,1)>0,Hans!C2,))),"")

Comment: I want to search for numbers and weeks - then there is a match, its give me the output.

Comment: The output with ', works then I remove ' from the string in the cell and press: CTRL+SWIFT+ENTER.

Comment: Doesn't `CELL("filename", $A$1), LEN(CELL("filename", $A$1))-FIND("]", CELL("filename", $A$1)))` simply return the name of the worksheet the formula is being inserted into? For `Sheets(B).Range("J2:J" & y)` that would be *Hans*.

Comment: If I debug the formula, and remove ' from =IFERROR, then the formula do what it need to.
So I don't get it, what you mean - sorry.

Comment: I'm looking at ways to reduce your formula to get it below the 255 array formula limit or make it a non-array formula; there seems to be several places where significant reductions can be made.

Comment: If you can fix it so that it stays within 255 characters - it would be perfect. I can not really see how it can be done smarter. But I'm not an expert either.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Jeeped, can you help me to make it?

Comment: I can **help** but I'm not going to do your work for you particularly when some of the questions posed in the comments here were deemed not worth answering. FYI, they **were** important. The CELLS question alone could have reduced your formula substantially. I'm simply not going to play guessing games with you. Provide an [mcve] detailing where the formula is intended to go and supply enough sample data to reproduce the issue. If you have trouble getting sample data into your question, create a shared google sheets spreadsheet of redacted data and post the shared link back in your question.